# Corda schema update

Tags: corda

I am researching options for Corda database upgrades and I am puzzled with two different approaches described for Corda Open Source
https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#state-schema-versioning
vs Corda Entrerprize: https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html.

In Corda Opensource it is suggested to create several mapped schemas on java side. 
And on Corda enterprise it is mentioned that liquibase scripts are used to modify database part.

Are two of the options mutually exclusive? I.e. if I use liquibase to update schema there is no need to add several mapped schemas?
And if I use MappedSchemas in java side, I do not need the liquibase scripts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Liquibase support is added only in Enterprise. To create tables in Corda Enterprise, you need to add Liquibase scripts which supports automated database versioning.
2. Liquibase is not supported in Corda Open source. In Corda open source you will define your tables as Hibernate JPA entity. The table gets created in the database as a Hibernate entity. Even if you add Liquibase script in Open Source, it will be ignored and Hibernate entity will be created instead.
3. Liquibase is added in Corda Enterprise which helps developers write database agnostic scripts and helps them with automated database migration/versioning.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Sneha! Why Can'not I manually run liquibase scripts with Corda Opensource?

Comment: You can do that.

Comment: In that case, can you please answer my initial  question?

Comment: Yes as far as I am aware, the node will not complain since the required table is already created in the database.

Comment: Hi Sneha!
The initial question was this one:
>Are two of the options mutually exclusive? I.e. if I use liquibase to update schema there is no need to add several mapped schemas? And if I use MappedSchemas in java side, I do not need the liquibase scripts?

Comment: you can ping me on slack if you need more assistance